# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Web.Extensions Version 1.0.61025

Tags: asp.net

I was trying to install ajax in my website. But i got the following error. I am using asp.net 2.0 and the steps i followed are as follows.

1. Downloaded and run the the ASPAJAXExtSetup.msi from the [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883#top)
2. Modified the web.config as mentioned by [this link](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx)

After doing the above things when i run the applicaion i got the  error.

I googled it out and i found out that i need to refer System.Web.Extension.dll into bin directory.But i cannot find the dll in the folder **C;/ProgramFiles/Microsoft ASP.NET /ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions/v 1.0.61025**.

Is this the real cause of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because you did not import the reference to your project.  The resulting XML will be added when you do so.  To do this:

1. Right click on your web project and select Property Page In the
   Reference window
2. You should see a reference for
   System.Web.Extension, if you do not, you need to add it.
3. Click the "Add Button" and select the .Net Tab.
4. Scroll Down to the System.Web.Extension component and select OK

This should add the reference and DLL to your project.  If not, let me know.